# Remove immediate duplicate items

Tags: javascript, arrays, unique

I need to remove immediately-subsequent duplicate items from a given array `items`.

For example, if I have this array:

```json
[1, 2, 2, 3, 3, 1, 1, 4, 5, 5, 4, 4, 4, 6, 2]
```

… this is what the result should be:

```json
[1, 2, 3, 1, 4, 5, 4, 6, 2]
```

If I use `[...new Set(items)]`, I then get an array of unique items, which is **not**  what I'm after:

```
[1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6]
```

How can I do it (ideally, in *O(n)* time)?

Comment: Yes, iterate through the source array building a new array, and skip elements of the source array that are repeat values. Basically exactly what you would do with pencil and paper.

Comment: `a.filter((e, i, arr) =>  e !== arr[i + 1])` ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```js
const arr = [1, 2, 2, 3, 3, 1, 1, 4, 5, 5, 4, 4, 4, 6, 2]

const newArr = arr.filter((value, index) => value !== arr[index - 1])
```

Answer (score 1):

```
function removeImmediateDuplicates(arr) {
  const result = [];
  const n = arr.length;

  for (let i = 0; i < n; i++) {
    if (arr[i] !== arr[i + 1]) {
      result.push(arr[i]);
    }
  }

  return result;
}

const items = [1, 2, 2, 3, 3, 1, 1, 4, 5, 5, 4, 4, 4, 6, 2];
const result = removeImmediateDuplicates(items);
console.log(result); // Output: [1, 2, 3, 1, 4, 5, 4, 6, 2]
```

Answer (score 0):

array filter method:

```js
const
  arr = [1, 2, 2, 3, 3, 1, 1, 4, 5, 5, 4, 4, 4, 6, 2]
, res = arr.filter((val,i,{[i-1]:prev})=> prev!==val )
  ;
console.log(JSON.stringify(res));
```

array reduce method:

```js
const
  arr = [1, 2, 2, 3, 3, 1, 1, 4, 5, 5, 4, 4, 4, 6, 2]
, res = arr.reduce((r,v,i,{[i-1]:p})=>( p!==v ? r.push(v) : null, r),[])
  ;
console.log(JSON.stringify(res));
```